# strtok. How to finish parsing

Tags: c, strtok

On page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb.aspx there is text that I must to finish parsing of previous string before to parse next:

> Note
>
> Each function uses a thread-local static variable for parsing the
>   string into tokens. Therefore, multiple threads can simultaneously
>   call these functions without undesirable effects. However, within a
>   single thread, interleaving calls to one of these functions is highly
>   likely to produce data corruption and inaccurate results. When parsing
>   different strings, finish parsing one string before starting to parse
>   the next. Also, be aware of the potential for danger when calling one
>   of these functions from within a loop where another function is
>   called. If the other function ends up using one of these functions, an
>   interleaved sequence of calls will result, triggering data corruption.

What does that mean? For example I need only first token. Must I continue call `strtok(null, )` to finish or I can call `strtok(string2, )`?

Comment: This has to do with multithreading, not much related to successive calls from same thread.

Comment: There is no need that the must be called until it returns NULL.

Comment: E.g "A\tB,C,D\tE", You will not be able to cut out to continue the third field if you use the strtok is to cut out the token of the second field with comma when you have a cut out of the token in the tab.

Answer (score 1):

> Must I continue call strtok(null,) to finish or I can call
>   strtok(string2,)?

If you just need first token fetch it and continue using it no need to call `strtok(NULL,"<delimiter>")` after fetching the first token. Since strtok() uses internal state and if you wish to break the same string into multiple tokens then you need to pass `NULL` after passing the actual string during the first time.

The initial call should be

```
strtok(string2,"<delimiter>");
```

Comment: But obviously you will want to put a space after that comma, otherwise it won't compile...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a program without successive `strtok` calls between different threads you can just get the first token as you want to, and then continue using `strtok` on other strings without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` must be used from 2nd and up, `string2` would begin a new sequence. If you need only first *token* call it just once.

See  [man strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

If you have more threads calling `strtok` the last call to `strtok` *win* making the previous invalid (use `strtok_r`).

Also, if you need only one token, may be you can take a look to `strsep` ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strsep))